# Analog Tv Tuner drivers for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, tv, tuner-card, v4l2

I was searching for the Analog usb (stick) tv tuner card for Ubuntu, but I have not found single such tv tuner card with ubuntu drivers available. I tried to search for the open source tv tuner drivers for linux and then what I found is [this](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers). Does anybody tried these drivers with analog tv tuner USB stick? Will it work with analog tv tuner cards or is it only for DVB devices?

Do I have any other option in terms of drivers or is there any tuner device available with Ubuntu drivers?

I had found one such card 'Aver Media Volar go' but currently it is not available and I heard from vendors that Aver Media has stopped its production.

**Edit:**
Do these drivers on linuxtv.org are only applicable for DVB-T mode or I can use it for normal mode like when set top box is connected to tuner.

Comment: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Device_Information